# Creating a layout per workspace in xmonad with a list of layouts (or: how to create a recursive data type automatically)

Tags: haskell, recursion, xmonad

The basic idea is this: I have a list of workspaces, each with its own unique layout. I want to create the main layout hook from all those specific layouts, without writing `onWorkspace "1" (Layout Full)` and chaining them all manually, with something like

```
layouts = onWorkspace "1" layout1 $ onWorkspace "2" layout2 ... $ Layout Full --last layout is the default
```

The reason this is tricky is the return type of `onWorkspace "a" layout` - it returns `LayoutClass l Window=> PerWorkspace Layout l Window`

Now, the PerWorkspace described above stands the type constrain of `LayoutClass l Window`, combining it with something like `foldl ($) (Layout Full)` wont work because it creates the recursive data `LayoutClass l Window=> PerWorkspace Layout (LayoutClass l Window=> PerWorkspace Layout l Window) Window`, with a layer for each workspace.

So my question is this- given an array of `LayoutClass l Window=> PerWorkspace Layout l Window`, how can I chain them into `LayoutClass l Window=> PerWorkspace Layout (LayoutClass l Window=> PerWorkspace Layout l Window) Window` however deep it need to be and then apply them the final, default layout?

My attempt so far:

```
layouts = foldr ($) (Layout Full) $ map (\w -> onWorkspace (name w) (layout w)) myworkspaces
```

throws in compilation:

```
xmonad.hs:23:37: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘PerWorkspace Layout Layout Window’
                 with ‘Layout Window’
  Expected type: [Layout Window -> Layout Window]
    Actual type: [Layout Window -> PerWorkspace Layout Layout Window]
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘map (\ w -> onWorkspace (name w) (layout w)) myworkspaces’
  In the expression:
    foldr ($) (Layout Full)
    $ map (\ w -> onWorkspace (name w) (layout w)) myworkspaces
  In an equation for ‘layouts’:
      layouts
        = foldr ($) (Layout Full)
          $ map (\ w -> onWorkspace (name w) (layout w)) myworkspaces
```